# C# DataTable objects output

Tags: c#

How do I output the value of this table because it outputs to me:

```
lab5.FootballTeam - lab5.Tournament - System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]
lab5.FootballTeam - lab5.Tournament - System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]
lab5.FootballTeam - lab5.Tournament - System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]
```

And i need:

```
title1 city1 1910 turnirtilte1 true 1950 1980 1989
title2 city2 1920 turnirtilte1 true 1950 1991 1995
title3 city3 1930 turnirtilte1 true 1950 2002
```

Here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace lab5
{
    class FootballTeam
    {
        public string title;
        public string city;
        public int foundationYear;
        public FootballTeam(string title1, string city1, int foundationYear1)
        {
            title = title1;
            city = city1;
            foundationYear = foundationYear1;
        }

        public string Print()
        {
            return $"{title},{city},{foundationYear}";
        }
    }

    class Tournament
    {
        public string title;
        public Boolean international;
        public int foundationYear;
        public Tournament(string title1, Boolean international1, int foundationYear1)
        {
            title = title1;
            international = international1;
            foundationYear = foundationYear1;
        }

        public string Print()
        {
            return $"{title},{international},{foundationYear}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var date1 = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1);
            HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int>();
            HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int>();
            HashSet<int> set3 = new HashSet<int>();
            HashSet<int> turnir = new HashSet<int>();
            FootballTeam team1 = new FootballTeam("title1", "city1", 1910);
            FootballTeam team2 = new FootballTeam("title2", "city2", 1920);
            FootballTeam team3 = new FootballTeam("title3", "city3", 1930);
            Tournament tournament1 = new Tournament("turnirtilte1", true, 1950);
            turnir.Add(1980);
            turnir.Add(1989);
            turnir.Add(1991);
            turnir.Add(1995);
            turnir.Add(2002);
            set1.Add(1980);
            set1.Add(1989);
            set2.Add(1991);
            set2.Add(1995);
            set3.Add(2002);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("FootballTeam", typeof(FootballTeam));
            dt.Columns.Add("Tournament", typeof(Tournament));
            dt.Columns.Add("HashSet", typeof(HashSet<int>));
            dt.Rows.Add(team1, tournament1, set1);
            dt.Rows.Add(team2, tournament1, set2);
            dt.Rows.Add(team3, tournament1, set3);
            var selectedBooks = dt.Select();
            foreach (var b in selectedBooks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", b["FootballTeam"], b["Tournament"], b["HashSet"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the `Print()` methods so they override `ToString()`. The `WriteLine()` method automatically calls `ToString()` when formatting the value into the template.

Alternatively, you can change `b["FootballTeam"]` to `b["FootballTeam"].Print()`, and do the same for the Tournament.

Then you also need to loop through your HashSet. Collections in .Net will never automatically print the items. You have to do that work yourself to print each individual item yourself. Sometimes you can use [`String.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) to help with this.